# Import data with strings looking like error values from Excel to Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I try to import data from Excel to Pandas dataframe using read_excel function. Unfortunately provider of Excel spreadsheet used to put into some cells value "#N/A", which is interpreted by Pandas as incorrect value and casted into NaN. #N/A is an Excel error, which occurs when lookup function cannot return any value, however in this case it is manually entered by user and must be fetched into dataframe as string "#N/A".

Is there any way to make Pandas copy the value as it is without interpreting it as Excel error? It is meant to be part of automated process so preferably it should be done without manual modification of the spreadsheet before process starts.

Comment: @BigBen - Unfortunatelly it doesn't work.

Comment: Your "strings that look like error values" are *actually* error values. If they were entered in Excel as `'#N/A`, with a backtick, then they would be strings, and `keep_default_na=False` should work fine. Otherwise you can use the solution in the linked thread, or perhaps work with a different library than pandas.

Comment: @BigBen Thank you! Unfortunately the problem cannot be solved in my case (suggested solution doesn't work for me as well as for author of the question you sent), but I will try openpyxl instead.